# MYSQL HAVING with nonexistent entries

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

i want to select a max of s2.maxcol or 0 if there are no entries.
So far this works, but if there is no corresponding entry it is not returned:

```
SELECT MAX( s2.maxcol) AS max_col, s1 . *
FROM table AS s1
LEFT JOIN table AS s2 ON s2.parent = s1.id
GROUP BY s1.id
HAVING max_col <100
```

But i also want to have the rows where the left join returns no corresponding entry (so max(s2.maxcol) should be 0.

How can i solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed `HAVING max_col <100` to `HAVING max_col is NULL or max_col <100`
which works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I just gave this a quick look and have to leave right now. But maybe `COALESCE` might help. Here is the [info](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Maybe something like this? (UNTESTED!)

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(s2.maxcol), 0) AS max_col, s1 . *
FROM table AS s1
LEFT JOIN table AS s2 ON s2.parent = s1.id
GROUP BY s1.id
HAVING max_col <100
```

Hope that helps. Bye!